# TFS 2018 - PROJECT MAPPING

Tags: tfs, project

I am working with TFS 2018 where I modify the templates of the work items so that they have the data that I need, that is, add new fields.
I need these fields to be synchronized to Project in a particular field, what happens to me is that they are not impacting on project.
Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Do you mean Synchronize Team Foundation Server with Project Server? Or just want to Synchronize data between work item fields?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean [Synchronize Team Foundation Server with Project Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/reference/tfs-ps-sync/synchronize-tfs-project-server?view=vsts), then TFS 2018 no longer support native integration with Office Project Server. You need to find the [third-party support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/reference/tfs-ps-sync/sync-ps-tfs?view=vsts).

> TFS 2017 and later versions no longer support native integration with
>   Office Project Server. If you upgrade to TFS 2017 or want to use a
>   third party option, see [Synchronize TFS with Project Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/reference/tfs-ps-sync/sync-ps-tfs?view=vsts).

If you mean Synchronize data between work item fields, then you can apply [Assign value rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/reference/xml/apply-rule-work-item-field?view=vsts#assign-value-rules) to a filed, e.g COPY rule : `Copies a specified value to a field when a user creates or modifies a work item.`